# Change the code from child process exec to spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

I've node app and I use the child_process.**exec** api which working OK, the issue is that there is maxBuffer thing that we have trouble with hence I want to change it to work with **spawn**

The code **before** was like (this code works fine I just need to pass cmd and options and it was doing the job...)

```
var child = child_process.exec(cmd,options, function (error) {
....
});
```

Now i've change it to spawn and it doesnt work

```
    var child = child_process.spawn(cmd, options);

    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });
```

**Here Im getting error**

```
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
stderr: execvp(): No such file or directory
```

Any Idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting a child process with spawn, you need to separate the command from the args.

If you had:

```
child_process.exec('somecmd somearg somearg2', options, function() {...});
```

You now need:

```
child_process.spawn('somecmd', ['somearg', 'somearg2'], options);
```

If there are no arguments to use, pass an empty array:

```
child_process.spawn('somecmd', [], options);
```

Comment: HI Amit thanks but what is the arges which I need to use,I just have the cmd and options?

Comment: then use an empty array.

Comment: Thanks Amit, I've tried exaclty like you said with empty array and Im getting the same erorr,any other idea? since when I run the same cmd&options with exec this works...

Comment: hi this is some internal command that works in out landscape with the exec API , I guess is should work also with spawn...

Comment: HI Amit,there is other api which I can use, I cannot use the exec since the maxBuffer property,I check with spawn but it appear that this is not working...I need just to pass the command and options to childProcess...Thanks!

Comment: @JhonD I don't know of any other relevant API, but I'm confident you're not using it correctly, and I ask again, what (***exactly***) is `cmd`? what value (string) does it hold?

Comment: I've execute command to create node runtime for some process...if there no other API why when I put the command in child_process.exec this is working and not with spawn ?  I use the child_process.exec('somecmd', options);  with the callback which handle success or failure and I switch to the same command  child_process.spawn('somecmd', [], options);

Comment: For the last time, **WHAT EXACTLY IS YOUR COMMAND?** I'm trying to help, but please, **ANSWER THIS VERY SIMPLE QUESTION**. Is the string you're passing as the first parameter `'somecmd'` (I doubt it)? Can you **PLEASE** tell what it is?

Comment: Hi Amit give me 5 min I need to run it on cloud foundry so it can take some time....

Comment: Hi Again this is the command : app.1DtNuN/vendor/node0.12/bin/node node_modules/app/appr.js

Comment: Ok... now we're getting somewhere. As I explained before, arguments go into the array. anything after the space (after ".../bin/node") is an argument. split that as I explained, try again.

Comment: Thanks but not sure that I fully got it can you please update the answer?

Comment: I don't know what 'app.1DtNuN' is, but if you normally invoke node with 'app.1DtNuN/vendor/node0.12/bin/node' then this is what you pass as the first parameter, and `['node_modules/app/appr.js']` as your second parameter. that's it.

Comment: so in the command(cmd) I dont need to pass anything ?just to split it and to put it in the array ?

Comment: in the `cmd` you put the exact string you'd use if you just run node from command line, without any parameters (no flags, no script to load - *nothing*). all the parameters (just the script by what you showed) go into the array.

Comment: I will test it tomorrow since to change this can take some time :( can you please update the answer with the exact things which I need to do and I'll mark it as solved,meanwhile 1+ thank you very much sir!hope it really works...

Comment: one last thing can you please update the answer with the string I provide as constant where to put where this can be very helpful!

Comment: @JhonD - I really hope that solves your problem, I appreciate the +1, and I'd also appreciate a "solved" if that really works, but I don't think adding the exact command line is relevant for the answer. that's just your specific use case, not the general case. Good luck! (what *YOU* should use is: `child_process.spawn('app.1DtNuN/vendor/node0.12/bin/node', ['node_modules/app/appr.js'], options);`)

Comment: Thanks so maybe in the comment you can do this :) since I dont want to be confused...im struggling on it two days